# OpenCv installation problems. unsatisifedlinkerror java

Tags: opencv

I have been trying for ages now to get opencv installed and running. I've read every guide and post I can find but I'm still having no luck. Here's what i've done:

1. installed opencv in default directory of c:\opencv
2. installed microsoft redistributables for x64 and x86 latest versions
3. added C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin to my path
4. created a project with the following code

import org.opencv.core.Core;

```
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;

public class Demo
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
      Mat mat = Mat.eye( 3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
      System.out.println( "mat = " + mat.dump() );
   }
}
```

1. created a library in eclipse containing opencv-247.jar
2. added the native path for the jar ( not the library ) as C:/opencv/build/java/x64

When I run the program I get the following error

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception UnsatisfiedLinkError))  
    Mat.n_eye(int, int, int) line: not available [native method]    
    Mat.eye(int, int, int) line: 1467   
    Demo.main(String[]) line: 10
```

I would love any help anyone can give. I'm going nuts here!

Comment: ps my java jdk is 64 bit and so is my windows 8 installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need import Core class too

you can do with :

**import org.opencv.core.Core;**

Comment: Holy crap that got it! Weeks that took! Thanks!